# How to dynamically cast a variable to Option

Tags: scala, dynamic-cast

I'd like to cast variables dynamically to `Option[T]`. The semantic is: if variable `x` matches `T` type, then cast should return `Some(x)` and it should return `None` otherwise. Using single map invocation is much cleaner than using `isInstanceOf[T]` accompanying `asInstanceOf[T]` or building monstrous case switches.

I had tried simple code below

```
object OptionCast {
  def apply[T](source : Any) : Option[T] = source match {
    case s : T => Some(s)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

but it ignores types actually: `OptionCast[Int]("some").map(_ + 2)` gives me type error.

How should I rewrite this code?

Comment: try: source : T instead?

Comment: @StefanKunze The problem is that apply result type is erased (Option[T]), not the input one

Comment: Dynamic cast is needed for casting from Any type

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that `T` is erased -- methods in bytecode do not have type parameters, so `T` is erased to `Object` and, therefore, true for everything.

This works, with some limitations:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
object OptionCast {
  def apply[T : ClassTag](source : Any) : Option[T] = source match {
    case s : T => Some(s)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

There are two important limitations here:

1. It cannot check type parameters, because type parameters are erased are runtime. That means you can call `OptionCast.apply[List[Int]](List("a"))` and it will return `Some(List("a"))`. To get around that, you have to get around type erasure.
2. Any `AnyVal` class will be boxed, so you have to check against `java.lang.Integer` to catch `Int`, and so on.